# How do you display an image in UIKit in XCode with the PHImageRequestID?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm a complete beginner to UIKit and have been trying to get the AVCam demo by Apple to work with deferred photo processing (WWDC feature) and so far I have been able to get to obtain the image ID of the photo taken but have no idea how to create an image out of it and display it onto the phone screen. Right now, I have a variable that holds the PHImageRequestID of the live photo that was just taken. I'm also trying to create a button that appears after the image is taken that the user will press that makes the image appear.

I tried to use a PH Photo Picker but it didn't utilize the PHImageRequestID so I need to find a way to be able to display an image with its ID.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. When you say, for example, *"I am doing [this], how do I then do [that]"* ... it is **very** difficult to help when we don't see your code related to *"doing [this]"*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.